# Get string names from another form

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to do a project which contains databases, and I'm having trouble that while I was making the database I put all the strings in another form, now I can't figure it out how can I take string names from one form to another, I'm gonna post a code which contains the string names and maybe someone can help. I'm going to highlight the problem where I'm having with "//" what should i write here to string names from the another form called "KlausimuContracts"

KlausimuContracts form:

```
`package com.example.laivumusis;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class KlausimuContracts {

    private KlausimuContracts(){}

    public static class KlausimuLentele implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String _ID = "ID";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "klausimyno_klausimai";
        public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "klausimai";
        public static final String COLUMN_OPTION1 = "pasirinkimas1";
        public static final String COLUMN_OPTION2 = "pasirinkimas2";
        public static final String COLUMN_OPTION3 = "pasirinkimas3";
        public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER_NR = "atsakymo_nr";
    }
}`
```

Database form:

```
package com.example.laivumusis;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.example.laivumusis.KlausimuContracts.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class KlausimynoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Klausimynas.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public KlausimynoDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                KlausimuLentele._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER" +
                ")";


        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
        fillKlausimuLentele();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addData(ContentValues contentValues){
        getWritableDatabase().insert(KlausimuContracts.KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME,null );
        return data;
    }

    public boolean atnaujintiData (String ID, String klausimai) { // here is the problem 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KlausimuLentele._ID, ID);
        contentValues.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION, klausimai);

        db.update(KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {ID});
        return true;
    }


    private void fillKlausimuLentele() {
        Klausimai q1 = new Klausimai("Kelintais metais buvo išleista java proogramavimo kalba?", "1991", "1995", "1989", 1);
        addQuestion(q1);
        Klausimai q2 = new Klausimai("Ar destytojas pasigailės mūsų?", "Priklauso nuo darbo", "Priklauso nuo pingų", "Prklauso nuo nuotaikos", 1);
        addQuestion(q2);
        Klausimai q3 = new Klausimai("Kai sunervina žaidimas koks geriausias būdas iš jo išeiti?", "Alt+F4", "Quit To desktop", "Ištraukti maitinimo laida",1);
        addQuestion(q3);
        Klausimai q4 = new Klausimai("A is correct again", "A", "B", "C", 1);
        addQuestion(q4);
        Klausimai q5 = new Klausimai("B is correct agian", "A", "B", "C", 2);
        addQuestion(q5);
    }

    private void addQuestion(Klausimai klausimai) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION, klausimai.getKlausimas());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION1, klausimai.getPasirinkimas1());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION2, klausimai.getPasirinkimas2());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION3, klausimai.getPasirinkimas3());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR, klausimai.getAtsakymoNr());
        db.insert(KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    }

    public List<Klausimai> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Klausimai> klausimuSarasas = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Klausimai klausimai = new Klausimai();
                klausimai.setKlausimas(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
                klausimai.setAtsakymoNr(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR)));
                klausimuSarasas.add(klausimai);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return klausimuSarasas;

    }
}
```

Debugger problem:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ID in "UPDATE klausimyno_klausimai SET klausimai=?,ID=? WHERE ID = ?"
```